# Solution verification: characteristic polynomial of $\mathcal{A}^{-1} $

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, operator-theory, characteristic-polynomial

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an invertible operator on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ of dimension $n$. Let $g(t)= a_0  + a_1 t + a_2 t^2+ ... + a_n t^n  $ be a characteristic polynomial of $\mathcal{A}^{-1}$.  Then, from Cayley-Hamilton theorem, we obtain: $g(\mathcal{A}^{-1})= a_0 \mathcal{I} + a_1 \mathcal{A}^{-1} + a_2 (\mathcal{A}^{-1})^2 +... + a_n (\mathcal{A}^{-1})^n= \mathcal{O} $, where  $\mathcal{I} $ and  $\mathcal{O}$ are an identity and zero  operator, respectively.  Hence, $  (\mathcal{A}^{-1})^n = -\frac{ a_0}{a_n} \mathcal{I} - \frac{ a_1}{a_n} \mathcal{A}^{-1} - ... - \frac{ a_{n-1}}{a_n} (\mathcal{A}^{-1})^{n-1} $.  If we compose  both sides of last equality with operator $\mathcal{A}^{n-1}$, then we get:

$ \mathcal{A}^{-1} =-\frac{ a_0}{a_n} \mathcal{A}^{n-1} -\frac{ a_1}{a_n} \mathcal{A}^{n-2}- ... - \frac{ a_{n-1}}{a_n} \mathcal{I}  $.

Is this  reasoning correct, can we express $\mathcal{A}^{-1}$ in terms of $\mathcal{A}$  this way? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning is absolutely correct.

You could obtain the same result by using the characteristic polynomial $p_A(t) = \det ( A-tI)$ of $A.$ It is even a classical method, when the constant coefficient of this $p_A$ is nonzero, to *prove* that $A$ is invertible and compute its inverse.

Moreover (just for fun), note that $$p_{A^{-1}}(t) = \det (A
^{-1}-tI)=
\det(-tA^{-1}(A-t^{-1}I))=(-t)^n\det(A^{-1})p_A(t^{-1}).$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it is a little different: if $\;A\;$ is invertible then using CH theorem

$$0=a_0I+a_1A+\ldots+A^n\stackrel{\cdot A^{-1}}\implies 0=a_0A^{-1}+a_1I+\ldots+aA^{n-1}\implies$$

$$A^{-1}=-\frac1{a_0}\left(a_1I+a_2A+\ldots+A^{n-1}\right)$$

since of course $\;a_0=\pm\det A\neq0\;$ .

This proves $\;A^{-1}\;$ is a polynomial in $\;A\;$ of degree less than $\;n=\;$ the matrix's order.

Comment: Thank you for this proof!  And just one question: in my proof, is it correct to start from CH theorem for inverse operator and proceed as I did? (if I understood your answer, it can be done that way, but just to be sure)

Comment: No, it isn't because you're assuming $\;A^{-1}\;$ is a zero of the characteristic polynomial of $\;A\;$ , which may well be false...! Also remember that the characteristic polynomial of a matrix has highest coefficeint equal to $\;a_n=\pm1\;$

Comment: @DonAntonio I believe that the method in the original question is correct. Note that they define $g$ as the characteristic polynomial of $A^{-1}$ not $A$. (I agree your method is more practical as generally we know the characteristic polynomial of $A$ rather than $A^{-1}$)

Comment: @DonAntonio I defined $g$ to be a characteristic polynomial of $A^{−1}$, not of $A$

Comment: In fact this method produces exactly the same equation as the on given in the original question. (Of course we have to carefully change all the variables $a_n$ but we can do this as the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is closely related to that of $A^{-1}$, specifically we reverse the order of the $a_n$ (Assuming we let the characteristic polynomial be non monic))

Comment: @user122 Ok, I missed that point. Then it is fine since there's a very nice and pretty relation between a polynomial that has a non-zero number as a root and the inverse of that number...